# Tree Identification - Texas

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, shrubs

What is the species of this tree or shrub I saw in coastal southeast Texas? It is growing between a sidewalk and a curb. I would estimate its height at less than eight feet. The bark is kind of shaggy or craggy. Google image search suggests Sapindaceae for the family, but that covers a lot of ground.

The fruit somewhat resembles Rainier cherries.

The photograph was taken on August 22, 2021. I apologize for its quality.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try persimmon or Texas persimmon ; diospyros. They have fruit that looks like photo and holds until late summer and fall with little predation by insects or birds.
Leaves also look right. The TX variety is listed as shrub up to 40 ft. Bark with deep fissures that tend to make a checkered pattern ( characteristic pattern). Personally the fruit is very astringent but freezing makes it very good. Because a natural freeze may come so late , it is much better to put ripe fruit in the freezer. I am familiar with the tree , however I am also looking in "Trees of East TX", Robert  A. Vines, University of TX Press, 1977. Unfortunately it is such a limited edition book , the great many illustrations are drawings, not in color.

Comment: The fruit doesn't look like any persimmon I've seen. They look more like Rainier cherries except that the fruit stems and the tree bark aren't right.